# Turn.js shadow effect missing on corners

Tags: shadow, turnjs

I've been trying to figure out why I cannot seem to get that nice shadow effect around the corner of the magazine for weeks. I don't even know what css class should be applied in order to obtain that effect. I've been also researching the web for some kind of solution but unsuccessfully so far. A bit of help would be greatly appreciated. Here's a link to my developping server http://vm.penegalab.com ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   .btn-custom {
       background-color: hsl(94, 94%, 30%) !important;
       background-repeat: repeat-x;
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e2fdcd", endColorstr="#42ef84");
       background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e2fdcd), to(#429404));
       background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e2fdcd, #429404);
       background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e2fdcd, #429404);
       background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #e2fdcd), color-stop(100%, #429404));
       background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e2fdcd, #429404);
       background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e2fdcd, #429404);
       background-image: linear-gradient(#e2fdcd, #429404);
       border-color: #429404 #429404 hsl(94, 94%, 15%);
       color: #333 !important;
       text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99);
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

}

Does that help? I got that on a website that i think had a button creator app? i can look for it if it the gradient effect you are referring to
This is a different website but even cooooollller!!
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/# play with the shadow effects. see what ya like

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
    .turn-page-wrapper{
       -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #999;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #999;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #999;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**LATEST ANSWER - 2020**

Wrap the `#flipbook` with a div. `Ex: .flipbook-container`

Then in your css file, add the following css part under the `.flipbook-container`

```
.shadow {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #ccc;
           box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #ccc;
}
```

That's it. Hope this answer might help someone!